# Kotlin: Trying to print multiple line with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, multiline

Im beginner with Kotlin / Java. I've tried to make a mobile app where the idea is simple: one button that prints current time to a text table and every press of a button prints new line.

I managed to make the button to print the current line, but when I press the button again it overwrites the time printed earlier.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val CryButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.CryButton)
    val CryTable = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.CryTable)


    CryButton.setOnClickListener {
        val current = LocalDateTime.now()
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh-mm")
        val formatted = current.format(formatter)

        CryTable.text = formatted.toString()
```

I have no idea how to make the code remember the last printed text and I can't find any solutions on the web.

Comment: welcome to Stack overflow :) with kotlin, there's no need to do a `findViewById` you can look here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html for more info :D

Comment: Hi! Yes, you don't have to use findViewById in kotlin. I don't really understand what you wanted to do but maybe you can set your last printed text into a global variable and every time you click on button you can check this variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use append -

```
val CryButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.CryButton)
val CryTable = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.CryTable)

CryTable.text = ""

CryButton.setOnClickListener {
val current = LocalDateTime.now()
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh-mm")
val formatted = current.format(formatter)

CryTable.append(formatted.toString())
```

Comment: Please mark it as correct answer if it solved your issue. Thank you :) @AleksiMMM

Answer (score 2):

What you need to change is instead of just replacing the text of the TextView you have to add a new line to it.

The solution to do this is to replace this line `CryTable.text = formatted.toString()` with this line `CryTable.text = CryTable.text + "\n" + formatted.toString()`

This will make it that your text view keeps the old text, add a new line to it, and then adds the new text.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with take old time in one variable and when you come to print new time, concat new time with old time with \n, It will work.